# Dereferencing pointer to incomplete type using a struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I have the following code in header "point.h":

```
#ifndef POINT_H_INCLUDED
#define POINT_H_INCLUDED

struct Point* createDefaultValues();

#endif // POINT_H_INCLUDED
```

The point.c file has the following code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
struct Point {
int x;
int y;
};


struct Point* createDefaultValues()
{
    struct Point* point;
    point = (struct Point*) malloc(sizeof(struct Point));
    point->x = 2;
    point->y = 1;
    return point;
};
```

And main.c consists of the following few lines:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "point.h"

int main()
{
    struct Point* cerc;
    cerc = createDefaultValues();
    printf("%d, %d", cerc->x, cerc->y);
    return 0;
}
```

I am getting dereferencing pointer to incomplete type error at printf() line. What should i do to repair it?

I know i can assign default values in struct, but i don't want to do that, i want to assign them only with the function found in my header.

Comment: why point.c file ends with "};". Shouldn't it be only with }?

Comment: In C, functions which take no arguments, should use type `void` in declaration `struct Point* createDefaultValues(void);`. Empty parenthesis means that function can take *any* number of arguments.

Comment: @Lundin That's function definition, not declaration.

Comment: Ah nevermind, I misunderstood. I thought he asked why the struct declaration ended with a semicolon. Comment deleted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can move the struct definition into header file:

```
 #ifndef POINT_H_INCLUDED
 #define POINT_H_INCLUDED

    struct Point {
      int x;
      int y;
    };


    struct Point* createDefaultValues();

    #endif // POINT_H_INCLUDED
```

and also include the header file in point.c

Comment: That does not solve my problem though. And it gives me an aditional compilation error: invalid application of 'sizeof' to incomplete type 'struct Point'

Comment: edit to mention you also need to include the header file in point.c

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked!
Should i declare all structs in my header file in the future?

Comment: @MarK If those structs are meant for external use, then yes. If they're an implementation detail, then no.

Comment: @MarK Making all structure implementations public is the traditional C approach. You can only access members or create instances if the implementation is known. The downside is that this introduces a compile-time dependency of the source files from the header file. About 20 years ago software projects became so large that it was impractical to re-compile everything just because a minor detail in an ubiquitous header changed. People then used "compilation firewalls" by using the "Pimpl Idiom". Herb Sutter's had a [gotcha of the week](https://herbsutter.com/gotw/_100/) about it (C++, but still).

Comment: This is poor program design. You shouldn't expose private member to the caller, it breaks private encapsulation. And private encapsulation is the whole reason why you would use incomplete type to begin with!

Answer (score 1):

The other way around would be to write two accessor functions, so you can get values of member via them instead of deferencing pointer. This approach might be better as it does not force you to place struct definition into public view.

For this, you could add intto `point.h`:

```
int getX(struct Point* point);
int getY(struct Point* point);
```

definitions go into `point.c`:

```
int getX(struct Point* point)
{
    return point->x;
}

int getY(struct Point* point)
{
    return point->y;
}
```

and replace it in main.c as:

```
printf("%d, %d", getX(cerc), getY(cerc));
```

By extending this, you could write setter functions, with things like validation, etc.

Comment: This is the correct answer. It is good design not to expose private members to the caller. Which is the reason why you use incomplete type to begin with.